# Python regex match letter sequences

Tags: python, regex, sequence

I want to make a regex to match "AGGH", "TIIK", "6^^?" or whatever but not "AGGA", "ABCD". Basically its the pattern of letters which matters. Is there a way to ask for a character you have or haven't previously had?

Comment: Why the requirement to use a regex for this?

Comment: Why exactly was `"AGGA"` not a match? It has a repeated character.

Comment: Yeah it has the first and last characters the same

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the pattern of your strings like this:

```
def pattern(s):
    d = {}
    return [d.setdefault(c, len(d)) for c in s]
```

Examples:

```
>>> pattern("AGGH")
[0, 1, 1, 2]
>>> pattern("TKKG")
[0, 1, 1, 2]
>>> pattern("AGGA")
[0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> pattern("ABCD")
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

This function makes it trivial to compare the pattern of two strings.

Comment: Thanks this is probably an easier way than trying to use regex

Comment: Clever, although it's not immediately obvious how it works. There's a slightly nicer version using a set - `s.add(c) or len(s)`.

Comment: @Thomas: Your version would always add `len(s)` to the pattern, since `set.add()` always returns `None`.  For the third example, this would result in `[0, 1, 1, 1]`.  You need to be able to loop up the indices of the characters added earlier, and a set will never be able to provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with a regex:

```
import re
strs=("AGGH", "TIIK", "6^^?" ,"AGGA", "ABCD")
p = re.compile('^(?P<one>.)(?P<two>.)(?P=two)(?!(?P=one)).$')
for s in strs:
    print s, p.match(s)
```

output:

```
AGGH <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011BFC38>
TIIK <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011BFC38>
6^^? <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011BFC38>
AGGA None
ABCD None
```

It's ugly, but it works. ;)  The period before the dollar sign is needed if you want to match to end of string, it consumes the actual character which is scanned by the (?!(?P=one)), which is a "negative lookahead assertion".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it could be simplified a bit by using `'^(.)(.)\2(?!\1).$'`, though that is slightly less clear in what the backreferences are referring to.

Comment: Yes, it can, just make sure to either escape your \'s or make the string a raw string as in `r'^(.)(.)\2(?!\1).$'`  (not saying you would, just that I **did** so thought I'd mention it. ;)

Comment: @JAB: The regex must be a raw string, otherwise `\1` and `\2` would be substituted by `chr(1)` and `chr(2)`.

Comment: Sven: Right, right. I find raw strings particularly useful for literal paths as well, actually. (Generally used when I'm working via the interpreter.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use substring search?

```
if "AGGH" in myStr:
    print "Success!"
```

Comment: I think he means all strings of the pattern "xyyz".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use conditional regex:

```
(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

See the details at http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Can you explain how to do it in this example